# CruiseControl.NET, VS 2010 and MVC 3 -- build error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, asp.net-mvc-3, cruisecontrol.net

Using the latest stable of CC.NET (new to it) and VS 2010.

I have defined project files for simple C# projects (4 in total) and one MVC Project.

The C# projects all compile correctly; however, the MVC3 project refuses to build.

I receive the following error in CC.NET:

> error MSB4019: The imported project
>   "C:\Program
>   Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path
>   in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on
>   disk.

After searching around and finding [This link](http://codebetter.com/kylebaley/2008/01/30/cruisecontrol-vs2008-and-asp-net-mvc/)
and [This other link](http://weblogs.asp.net/mnissen/archive/2006/06/19/Building-Web-Application-Projects-with-CCNET.aspx) (both referring to older versions of Visual Studio), it seemed that the general solution was to copy these files from that directory to the solution directory, add them to the solution with visual studio, and then change this line in the .csproj file:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
```

To this:

```
  <Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
```

However, this technique that worked for other VS Versions produces a different result in VS 2010: I receive the **.NET Project upgrade wizard**, as if upgrading the project from an old version of .NET. This strangeness is compounded by the fact that even if I do an undo and re-save the file **exactly as it was**, I receive the same message. It's as if the project has been marked dirty or something else has changed somehow.

Anyone have any ideas? This seems like it should be easier, but I can't seem to find another resource on it anywhere. Hoping StackOverflow will come through per usual. :)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Is visual studio 2010 installed on your build server?

Comment: @Daniel, thanks for the response! No, VS 2010 is not installed on the build server; that's why I'm doing this. The idea is to instead move the "hiccuping" file into the base of the solution and then change the .csproj file to reference it from the relative path of $(SolutionDir)\Microsoft.WebApplication.Targets. However, when I do that, VS seems to think that I'm upgrading from a previous version of .NET?

Answer (score 0):

The .targets file for v10.0 also has an assembly in the install folder - Microsoft.WebApplication.Build.Tasks.dll.  Did you copy that file over as well?  That will likely be necessary for the .targets file to work correctly, though that may not be the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like CC.Net isn't getting a proper reference to the msbuild executables.

Trying installing both of these on your build server (that's who I was able to get past that exact error).

Links :

[Windows SDK .Net 4](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8279)

[VS2010 Integrated Shell](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=115)